# preparing data for ggplot? multiple variables

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to wrestle my data into a better format to pass to ggplot.I'm trying to create something like [this](https://www.biostars.org/p/362024/).

However, I am stuck on pivot_longer!

```
testplotsummary <- ddply(d, c("CS.NCS", "Sex", "Group"), summarize,
                             N    = sum(!is.na(VARIABLE)),
                             mean = mean(VARIABLE, na.rm = TRUE),
                             sd   = sd(VARIABLE, na.rm = TRUE),
                             se   = sd / sqrt(N))


testplotsummaryomit <- na.omit(testplotsummary)

testplotsummaryomit
  CS.NCS    Sex Group  N     mean        sd       se
2     CS Female   Con  9 828.8667 176.11956 58.70652
3     CS Female   PNS  9 617.1462 167.48928 55.82976
4     CS   Male   Con 10 470.6272 132.01445 41.74663
5     CS   Male   PNS 10 521.3967 181.88043 57.51564
6    NCS Female   Con  9 793.1851 139.47968 46.49323
7    NCS Female   PNS  9 491.7112 115.47114 38.49038
8    NCS   Male   Con 10 415.2965 183.04720 57.88461
9    NCS   Male   PNS  9 337.3543  78.27023 26.09008

testplotsummaryomit %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = c("CS.NCS", "Group"), 
    names_to = "Type",
    values_to = "Value")
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 16 x 7
   Sex        N  mean    sd    se Type   Value
   <chr>  <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>  <chr>
 1 Female     9  829. 176.   58.7 CS.NCS CS   
 2 Female     9  829. 176.   58.7 Group  Con  
 3 Female     9  617. 167.   55.8 CS.NCS CS   
 4 Female     9  617. 167.   55.8 Group  PNS  
 5 Male      10  471. 132.   41.7 CS.NCS CS   
 6 Male      10  471. 132.   41.7 Group  Con  
 7 Male      10  521. 182.   57.5 CS.NCS CS   
 8 Male      10  521. 182.   57.5 Group  PNS  
 9 Female     9  793. 139.   46.5 CS.NCS NCS  
10 Female     9  793. 139.   46.5 Group  Con  
11 Female     9  492. 115.   38.5 CS.NCS NCS  
12 Female     9  492. 115.   38.5 Group  PNS  
13 Male      10  415. 183.   57.9 CS.NCS NCS  
14 Male      10  415. 183.   57.9 Group  Con  
15 Male       9  337.  78.3  26.1 CS.NCS NCS  
16 Male       9  337.  78.3  26.1 Group  PNS
```

How do I combine Group and CS.NCS in one column? Is this the best way to prep this data for ggplot?

Cheers!

Comment: Can you show your expected output?

Comment: https://www.biostars.org/p/362024/ something like this bargraph.

Comment: As far as I get it there is no need for `pivot_longer`. You can add a new col by pasting Group and CS.NSC together or by using `interaction(CS.NCS, Group)`. The new col can then be mapped on e.g. the `fill` aes.

Comment: okay i think i figured it out with ```unite```! thank you!

Comment: If you have already solved the question you can add that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in the end:

```
 corttestunitedcol <- unite(testplotsummaryomit, Treatment_Status, c(CS.NCS, Group), remove=TRUE)
```